# How to read and update value of nodes in an XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml document (actually a config file) loaded into an XDocument object, that contains an element like this:

```
  <ScheduledTasks>
    <add key="RelativePath" value="..\Scheduler\Tasks"/>
    <add key="SearchPauseInSeconds" value="10"/>
    <add key="MatrixAccount" value="95755UE93ZEb3fRZUSZ753K9FRS3O9DaDrJxtdiiZnm"/>
    <add key="MatrixPassword" value="95755UE93ZEb3fRZUSZ753K9FRS3O9DaDgKrn2e71"/>
  </ScheduledTasks>
```

How can I best retrieve (and update) the value of RelativePath, SeachPauseInseconds etc? They aren't XElements.

TIA.

Comment: The `XElement`s involved are the `add`s, with `XAttribute`s `key` and `value`.

Comment: I get it - The XElement "ScheduledTasks" contains several XElements "add", each with attributes "key" and "value". Is that it? So I need ot get the value of the "value" attribute in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var attribute =
   xDocument.Root.Elements()
                 .Single(element => element.Attribute("key").Value == "RelativePath")
                 .Attribute("value");
string oldValue = attribute.Value;   // to retrieve
attribute.Value = newValue;          // to update
```

Comment: That gaved me the clues I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They are attributes. Use `XElement.Attribute("attributeName")` to get them.

```
var items = (from i in scheduledTasksElement.Elements("add")
             select new
             {
                 KeyAttribute = i.Attribute("key"),
                 Key = (string)i.Attribute("key"),
                 ValueAttribute = i.Attribute("value"),
                 Value = (string)i.Attribute("value")
             }).ToList();
```

As you can see, you can easily cast `XAttribute` to other types like you can do with `XElement`.

You can also update the value:

```
items[0].KeyAttribute.Value = "newValue";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, create an extension method that will do it

```
public static void FindAndReplace(this XDocument doc, string key, string newValue)
{
    var elem = doc.Descendants("add")
                  .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Attribute("key").Value == key);
    if (elem != null)
        elem.Attribute("value").Value = newValue;
}
```

and use it like

```
doc.FindAndReplace("RelativePath", "..\Tasks");
```